# Linter error when using let and const for values within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, constants, let

I've got an array as such below

```
const [day, month, year] = dateSegments.map(segment => ((segment.length === 1) ? `0${segment}` : `${segment}`))
```

This is all well and good until 'year' gets reassigned in an if statement further down. 'Day' and 'month' remain as constants

```
 if (year.length === 2) {
   // blah blah blah loads of code not relevant
   year = `${mostLikelyCentury + year}`
 }

const finalDate = `${day}/${month}/${year}`
```

My linter is freaking out basically about the re-assigning of 'year' and i'm wondering how I can go about separating the values within the array into various lets and consts to avoid this linting error.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Just don't reassign to `year`?

```
const longYear = year.length === 2
  ? (() => {
      // blah blah blah loads of code not relevant
      return `${mostLikelyCentury + year}`
    })()
  : year;

const finalDate = `${day}/${month}/${longYear}`;
```

Alternatively, just change `const` to `let`.